# Solving boolean expressions using forward chaining

Tags: c++, algorithm, chaining, boolean-expression

Can someone help me with solving boolean expressions with the help of forward chaining. A good tutorial will also help me.

Example:
`A.(A + B) = A`

`A.(A + B) => A.A + A.B` [Applying distributive law]

`A.A + A.B => A + A.B`   [Applying idempotency law]

`A + A.B => A.(1 + B)`

`A.(1 + B) => A.(1) => A`

I have made huge efforts but still am unable to do this.
The procedure would require parsing the boolean expression and then recursive rule checking. I was thinking about creating a binary tree of the expression and then doing the rule check. Is my approach correct ? If not then suggest me an alternative.

Comment: I'm not clear on your exact requirements, but going to Disjunctive Normal Form does seem like a good first step.

Answer (score 1):

One approach to you problem could be to use a brute force method.  By this I mean: Try every possible combination of values `A` and `B` (or however many values you have) and generate a truth table of the results.

The following example illustrates this (although it is more in the style of `C` rather than `C++`).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <cassert>

const unsigned g_unValues = 2;

bool expression(int values[])
{
    return !!(values[0] * (values[0] + values[1]));
}

void truth_table(bool (*func)(int[]), unsigned nvalues);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    truth_table(expression, g_unValues);

    return 0;
}

void truth_table(bool (*func)(int[]), unsigned nvalues)
{
    assert(pow(2, nvalues) <= sizeof(unsigned));

    int values[nvalues];
    unsigned individuals[nvalues];
    unsigned result = 0;

    std::fill_n(individuals, nvalues, 0);

    // Display truth table header
    for (unsigned j = 0; j < nvalues; j++) std::cout << char('A'+j) << ' ';
    std::cout << "| Result" << std::endl;

    for (unsigned i = 1; i <= pow(2, nvalues); i++)
    {
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < nvalues; j++)
        {
            values[j] = i & 0x1<<j;
            if (values[j]) individuals[j] |= 0x1<<i;
        }

        bool eval = func(values);
        if (eval) result |= 0x1<<i;

        // Display truth table entry
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < nvalues; j++) std::cout << !!values[j] << ' ';
        std::cout << "| " << eval << std::endl;
    }

    for (unsigned j = 0; j < nvalues; j++)
    {
        if (result != individuals[j]) continue;
        std::cout << "Expression equivalence: " << char('A'+j) << std::endl;
        break;
    }
}
```

This code by itself is not very useful, but it might give you some ideas should you choose a brute force method.  You could adapt the code to create an `expression` from a user supplied string.  For expressions that don't simplify down to a single output you could replace the code which compares the input columns of the truth table with the result column with a method to generate a minimal string (a simplification of the initial input boolean expression).

Hopefully this is somehow useful, good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

i guess that the c++ Prop library ( http://www.cs.nyu.edu/leunga/prop.html ) could be useful for that : it provides symbolic term representation and rewriting support that could be used for implementing your system